# OK on msgbox return to previous value

Tags: vba, excel

The following code gives me a message box if the input in the cell is not a number and the text "Not relevant". So if i insert `"Bla bla"`, then I get the message `"Please insert a number"`.

When I press the OK button I can then insert a number, but until then I would like the cell to return to the previous accepted value, right after I press the OK button.

```
If Target.Address = Range("x").Address Then
    If Not IsNumeric(Range("x")) And InStr(1, (Range("x").Value), "Not relevant") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a number", vbCritical, "Distance between point loads, x-direction"
    End If
End If
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with Data Validation?

Comment: To expand on @Jeeped's comment: Setting Data Validation to "Allow: Custom" lets you put in a Formula, much like Conditional Formatting does.  Your conditions can be written as `=OR(ISNUMBER(A1), A1="Not relevant")`

Comment: Thank you. That comment is useful compared to the previous comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try undoing the last entry made,

```
If Target.Address = Range("x").Address Then
    If Not IsNumeric(target) And InStr(1, (Range("x").Value), "Not relevant") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a number", vbCritical, "Distance between point loads, x-direction"
        application.undo
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Easy, simple solution! Thank you!